# Java output console error message to file?

Tags: java, error-handling, console, text-files

I have a simple piece of code that outputs console text to a text file in Java:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("test2_output.txt"));
System.setOut(out);
```

However I require this text file to contain the error messages that is produced in the console but they are not included.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add:

```
System.setErr(out);
```

at the end.

Comment: Thanks very much. Did the job perfectly. I can't believe I couldn't find this statement anywhere on Google.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a `System.setErr()` call to redirect stderr.

Answer (score 3):

[`System.setErr(out)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr%28java.io.PrintStream%29)

Answer (score 2):

You're currently redirecting the standard output stream to a file. To redirect the standard *error* stream use

```
System.setErr(out);
```

- [`System.setErr()`<sup>javadoc</sup>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr%28java.io.PrintStream%29)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
PrintStream pst = new PrintStream("Text.txt");  
System.setOut(pst);
System.setErr(pst);
System.out.println("Hello, Finally I've printed output to file..");
```